# Проблема с проверкой наличия текста элемента в Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как получить текст элемента на старнице?

Я попробовал несколько способов, но первые 2 передают недостоверную информацию о содержании, а третий выглядит, как костыль.

Цель: Выйти из браузера как только элемент перестанет быть пустым

Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep


def document_initialised(driver):
    return driver.execute_script("return 'initialised'")


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

browser.get('https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/ru/Text')
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(document_initialised)

for i in range(10):
    print('fnd:', browser.find_element(value='target-dummydiv').text)
    print('src:', browser.execute_script("return document.getElementById('target-dummydiv');").text)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
    el = soup.find('div', id='target-dummydiv')
    translation = str(el.text).strip()

    print('bs4:', translation)

    if translation != '':
        break
    sleep(0.5)


generated_html = browser.page_source
browser.quit()
```

Вывод:

```
fnd: 
src: 
bs4: 

fnd: 
src: 
bs4: 

fnd: 
src: 
bs4: 

fnd:
src: 
bs4: Текст
```